# MGWT, GWT-phonegap app to android / iOS with internationalization

Tags: cordova, gwt, mgwt

Which internationalization technique would work best with an MGWT, GWT-phonegap app that is eventually to be converted using cordova to a native app for dynamic locale setting?

GWT provides static internationalization methodology (using Constants and Messages), but I do not think it is possible to set the locale dynamically with these.

Does MGWT provide any internationalization options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GWT static i18n. It produces a highly compact permutation for each language. Then you can package each permutation into a different Cordova (Phonegap) app - one per language. The advantage of this approach is that the app size will be much smaller as only one language is included. I would recommend this approach if your app has a lot of Strings and texts.

An alternative solution is to use [Cordova's globalization plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization/blob/master/doc/index.md). Note all the quirks, however, described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Andrei - to make sure I get you right, the GWT static i18n is basically the Constants and Messages interface? How would you go on with packaging each permutation in a different package? Selecting a single language each time before the build?

Comment: 1. Yes, Constants and Messages. 2. This probably the easiest way to do it.